# req.body is empty in express POST

Tags: node.js, angular, express

When i try to get my data back from my angular service, the req.body object appears empty. Even though the data is well transmitted in my angular http request.

```
  public reset(email: string): Observable<Boolean> {
    return this.http.post<Boolean>('/api/reset/reset', email); // email exists
  }
```

my route in express:

```
router.post('/reset', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.email); // undefined
    async.waterfall([
        function (done) {
            //code
        },
        function (token, done) {
           //code
        },
        function (token, user, done) { 
           //code
        }
});
```

Here is my app.js but i already checked the presence of bodyParser()

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const index = require('./routes/index');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


mongoose.connect('MYCONNECTIONSTRING', {
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE
  }, function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Connexion opened to mongodb!');
    }
});

app.use(index);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

This error has already been answered on stack overflow but all the answers i found did not solve my problem.

Comment: idk angular but i assume you need to tell angular under what name to send the param like: `('/api/reset/reset', {email: email})`

Comment: thank you ! it solved my problem!
I did not have that problem before because i think i was everytime sending objects

Comment: Can you mark the question as `CLOSED` so that people will not end up answering the same solution? cheers!

Comment: I have the choice between different options if i click "close", which one should i use ?